# Interleaving two NumPy arrays efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume the following arrays are given:

```
a = array([1, 3, 5])
b = array([2, 4, 6])
```

How would one interleave them efficiently so that one gets a third array like the following?

```
c = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

It can be assumed that `length(a) == length(b)`.

Comment: How about, same question, but you are trying to interleave matrices. That is a and b are 3 dimensional, and not necessarily the same size in the first dimension. Note:Only the first dimension should be interleaved.

Comment: adding a comment for anyone trying to search "translate Wolfram Mathematica's Riffle to Python" and not finding anything. hope this was picked up by your search engine

Answer (score 200, accepted):

I like [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays-efficiently/5347082#5347082).  I just wanted to add a more mundane, usual, and slightly more verbose solution.  I don't know which is more efficient.  I expect they will have similar performance.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,3,5])
b = np.array([2,4,6])

c = np.empty((a.size + b.size,), dtype=a.dtype)
c[0::2] = a
c[1::2] = b
```

Comment: Unless speed is really really important, I would go with this as it's much more comprehensible which is important if anyone is ever going to look at it again.

Comment: +1 I played around with timings and your code surprisingly seems to be 2-5x faster depending on inputs. I still find the efficiency of these types of operations to be nonintuitive, so it's always worth it to use `timeit` to test things out if a particular operation is a bottleneck in your code. There are usually more than one way to do things in numpy, so definitely profile code snippets.

Comment: @JoshAdel:  I guess if `.reshape` creates an additional copy of the array, then that would explain a 2x performance hit.  I don't think it always makes a copy, however.  I'm guessing the 5x difference is only for small arrays?

Comment: looking at `.flags` and testing `.base` for my solution, it looks like the reshape to 'F' format creates a hidden copy of the vstacked data, so it's not a simple view as I thought it would be. And strangely the 5x is only for intermediate sized arrays for some reason.

Comment: Another advantage of this answer is it's not limited to arrays of the same length. It could weave `n` items with `n-1` items.

Answer (score 106):

I thought it might be worthwhile to check how the solutions performed in terms of performance. And this is the result:

[image]

This clearly shows that the [most upvoted and accepted answer (Paul's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5347492/5393381) is also the fastest option.

The code was taken from the other answers and from [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468758/5393381):

```
# Setup
import numpy as np

def Paul(a, b):
    c = np.empty((a.size + b.size,), dtype=a.dtype)
    c[0::2] = a
    c[1::2] = b
    return c

def JoshAdel(a, b):
    return np.vstack((a,b)).reshape((-1,),order='F')

def xioxox(a, b):
    return np.ravel(np.column_stack((a,b)))

def Benjamin(a, b):
    return np.vstack((a,b)).ravel([-1])

def andersonvom(a, b):
    return np.hstack(zip(a,b))

def bhanukiran(a, b):
    return np.dstack((a,b)).flatten()

def Tai(a, b):
    return np.insert(b, obj=range(a.shape[0]), values=a)

def Will(a, b):
    return np.ravel((a,b), order='F')

# Timing setup
timings = {Paul: [], JoshAdel: [], xioxox: [], Benjamin: [], andersonvom: [], bhanukiran: [], Tai: [], Will: []}
sizes = [2**i for i in range(1, 20, 2)]

# Timing
for size in sizes:
    func_input1 = np.random.random(size=size)
    func_input2 = np.random.random(size=size)
    for func in timings:
        res = %timeit -o func(func_input1, func_input2)
        timings[func].append(res)

%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for func in timings:
    ax.plot(sizes,
            [time.best for time in timings[func]],
            label=func.__name__)  # you could also use "func.__name__" here instead
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('size')
ax.set_ylabel('time [seconds]')
ax.grid(which='both')
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
```

Just in case you have numba available you could also use that to create a function:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def numba_interweave(arr1, arr2):
    res = np.empty(arr1.size + arr2.size, dtype=arr1.dtype)
    for idx, (item1, item2) in enumerate(zip(arr1, arr2)):
        res[idx*2] = item1
        res[idx*2+1] = item2
    return res
```

It could be slightly faster than the other alternatives:

[image]

Comment: Also of note, the accepted answer is _way_ faster than the a native Python solution with [`roundrobin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the itertools recipes.

Comment: As per the chart, Paul's answer appears to be the slowest as the size of the data increases. However, @MSeifert says that 'This clearly shows that the most upvoted and accepted answer (Pauls answer) is also the fastest option.' Given MSeifert's statement, I believe I am reading the chart wrong. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @user3613932 Pauls answer is the blue line. And regarding the interpretation: Lower means faster. The blue and the yellow-greenish line (numba/Paul) are lowest and therefore fastest. The pink and purple (Tai and andersonvom) are highest and therefore slowest. I agree that the line colors are not really easy to differentiate but you should be able to easily reproduce the graph with the given code.

Comment: Nice plot. Can you share to us how to call the benchmark with the `Timing setup` as the input, also the `plot` function? Thank you.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni I don't know what you mean. The code in this answer should be runnable as-is (in a jupyter notebook environment at least). :)

Comment: @MSeifert sorry, did not see the scroll bar that show how to run the benchmark. Thanks.

Comment: The axes text is nearly *unreadable* in dark mode.

Answer (score 48):

Here is a one-liner:

```
c = numpy.vstack((a,b)).reshape((-1,),order='F')
```

Comment: Wow, this is so unreadable :) This is one of the cases where if you don't write a proper comment in the code, it can drive somebody crazy.

Comment: It's just two common numpy commands strung together. I wouldn't think it is that unreadable, although a comment never hurts.

Comment: @JohnAdel, well, it's not `numpy.vstack((a,b)).interweave()` :)

Comment: @Ilya: I would have called the function `.interleave()` personally :)

Comment: What does `reshape` do?

Comment: @JoshAdel I use that `interleave()` naming in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75519265/11671779)

Answer (score 26):

Here is a simpler answer than some of the previous ones

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,5])
b = np.array([2,4,6])
inter = np.ravel(np.column_stack((a,b)))
```

After this `inter` contains:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

This answer also appears to be marginally faster:

```
In [4]: %timeit np.ravel(np.column_stack((a,b)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.31 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit np.ravel(np.dstack((a,b)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.14 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit np.vstack((a,b)).ravel([-1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.08 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 10):

This will interleave/interlace the two arrays and I believe it is quite readable:

```
a = np.array([1,3,5])      #=> array([1, 3, 5])
b = np.array([2,4,6])      #=> array([2, 4, 6])
c = np.hstack( zip(a,b) )  #=> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: I like this one as most readable. despite the fact that it is the slowest solution.

Comment: Wrap `zip` in a `list` to avoid depreciation warning

Answer (score 8):

Improving [xioxox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays-efficiently/30555718#30555718):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,3,5])
b = np.array([2,4,6])
inter = np.ravel((a,b), order='F')
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do this but with multidimensional arrays along any axis. Here's a quick general purpose function to that effect. It has the same call signature as `np.concatenate`, except that all input arrays must have *exactly* the same shape.

```py
import numpy as np

def interleave(arrays, axis=0, out=None):
    shape = list(np.asanyarray(arrays[0]).shape)
    if axis < 0:
        axis += len(shape)
    assert 0 <= axis < len(shape), "'axis' is out of bounds"
    if out is not None:
        out = out.reshape(shape[:axis+1] + [len(arrays)] + shape[axis+1:])
    shape[axis] = -1
    return np.stack(arrays, axis=axis+1, out=out).reshape(shape)
```

Comment: +1 for such a generalized recipe (works with n-dim, interleaves along any axis, works for any number of input arrays, takes an optional `out` arg, and works for sub-classed arrays). Personally, I would prefer `axis` to default to `-1` rather than to `0`, but maybe that's just me. And you might want to link to this answer of yours, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162300/how-to-interleave-numpy-ndarrays/42162780https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162300/how-to-interleave-numpy-ndarrays/42162780), which actually asked for the input arrays to be n-dimensional.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is more readable than [JoshAdel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays-efficiently/5347082#5347082):

```
c = numpy.vstack((a,b)).ravel([-1])
```

Comment: `ravel`'s `order` argument in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) is one of `C`, `F`, `A`, or `K`.  I think you really want `.ravel('F')`, for FORTRAN order (column first)

Answer (score 3):

`vstack` sure is an option, but a more straightforward solution for your case could be the `hstack`:

```
a = array([1,3,5])
b = array([2,4,6])
hstack((a,b)) # Remember it is a tuple of arrays that this function swallows in.
array([1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6])
sort(hstack((a,b)))
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

And more importantly this works for arbitrary shapes of `a` and `b`.

Also you may want to try out `dstack`:

```
a = array([1,3,5])
b = array([2,4,6])
dstack((a,b)).flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

You’ve got options now!

Comment: -1 to first answer because question has nothing to do with sorting.  +1 to second answer, which is the best I've seen so far.  This is why multiple solutions should be posted as multiple answers.  Please split it into multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

One can also try `np.insert` (the solution was migrated from *[Interleave NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487928/interleave-numpy-arrays/48488404?noredirect=1#comment83969837_48488404)*).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,3,5])
b = np.array([2,4,6])
np.insert(b, obj=range(a.shape[0]), values=a)
```

Please see [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) and [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_insert.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner: `np.vstack((a,b)).T.ravel()`
One more: `np.stack((a,b),1).ravel()`

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner:

```
>>> c = np.array([a, b]).T.flatten()
>>> c
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2D numpy array:

```py
def interleave2d(a, b):
    """Interleave between columns of two arrays"""
    c = np.empty((len(a), a.shape[1] * 2), dtype=a.dtype)
    c[:, 0::2] = a
    c[:, 1::2] = b
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest function, but I needed one that could interleave an arbitrary number of matrices. Maybe helpful?

```
 def interleave_narr(*args):
        ''' Given N numpy arrays, interleave arr i+1...i+N'''
        m_sizes = 0
        for m in args:
                m_sizes += m.size
        o = np.empty((m_sizes,), dtype=args[0].dtype)
    
        n_mats = len(args)
        for ii in range(n_mats):
            o[ii::n_mats] = args[ii]
        return o
```