# Double the length of a python numpy array with interpolated new values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have an array of 5 numbers:

```
A = [10, 20, 40, 80, 110]
```

I need to create a new array with a 10nth length numbers.

The extra numbers could be the average number between the two # of `A`.

for example:
EDIT
    B = [10 , 15 , 20 ,30, 40, 60, 80, 95, 110 ]

Is it possible using a scipy or numpy function ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be `40` in `B`?

Comment: `sum([[x, sum([x,A[n+1]])/2] for n, x in enumerate(A) if n < len(A)-1],[])`

Comment: if the A include float numbers?

Comment: @user1640255 My answer works for floats. Hooked's answer will, too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [numpy.interp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
import numpy as np
Y = [10, 20, 40, 80, 110]
N = len(Y)
X = np.arange(0, 2*N, 2)
X_new = np.arange(2*N-1)       # Where you want to interpolate
Y_new = np.interp(X_new, X, Y) 
print(Y_new)
```

yields

```
[  10.   15.   20.   30.   40.   60.   80.   95.  110.]
```

---

Answer (score 5):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5347492/1258041):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([10, 20, 40, 80, 110])

In [3]: b = a[:-1] + np.diff(a)/2

In [4]: c = np.empty(2 * a.size -1)

In [5]: c[::2] = a

In [6]: c[1::2] = b

In [7]: c
Out[7]: array([  10.,   15.,   20.,   30.,   40.,   60.,   80.,   95.,  110.])
```

Comment: I like this better, much more "numpythonic". Although I realized that our two answers have different `dtype=float` and `dtype=int` in the final array (due to only dividing by even numbers).

Answer (score 2):

You're not quite doubling it, as you only what the average values in between. You are also missing `40` as @LevLevitsky points out in a comment.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([10, 20, 40, 80, 110])
avg = (A[:-1] + A[1:])/2

B = []
for x1, x2 in zip(A, avg):
    B.append(x1)
    B.append(x2)
B.append(A[-1])

B = np.array(B)
print B
```

Gives:

```
[ 10  15  20  30  40  60  80  95 110]
```

Comment: @user1640255 No problem, we are happy to help. Make sure that you up-vote and select the best answer. I see from your profile that you haven't accepted any answers yet. Do that! It helps us "close" a question, knowing that you've found a solution.