# numpy array : can not find how to transform the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays: `b` and `s`. And `len(b)==2*len(s)`.

`s` has the form:

```
l r l r l r ...
```

I what to transform it into:

```
0 0 l r 0 0 l r 0 0 l r ...
```

I'm doing it the easy way:

```
ix = 0
jx = 0
while ix < len(b):
    b[ix] = 0
    ix += 1
    b[ix] = 0
    ix += 1 
    b[ix] = s[jx]
    ix += 1
    jx += 1
    b[ix] = s[jx]
    ix += 1
    jx += 1
```

For speed, I'd like to do the same using numpy api but can't get something working.

What numpy methods should I be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May not be the smartest solution, but you can do it in two passes similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5347492/1258041):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: s = np.array([1, 2] * 3)

In [3]: b = np.zeros(2 * s.size)

In [4]: b[2::4] = s[::2]

In [5]: b[3::4] = s[1::2]

In [6]: b
Out[6]: array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the repetition in `b` and `s`, I automatically see a 2d solution:

```
b = np.zeros(N,4)
b[:,2:] = s.reshape(N,2)
b = b.flatten()
```

or appending the 0s onto the reshaped `s`:

```
b = np.hstack([np.zeros((10,2)),s.reshape(10,2)]).flatten()
```

or if we want to think in 3d

```
np.einsum('ij,k->ikj',s.reshape(N,2),[0,1]).flatten()
```

Same but with broadcasting

```
(s.reshape(10,2)[:,None,:]*np.array([0,1])[None,:,None]).flatten()
```