# Combine 2 lists in python such that elements at the corresponding index are together

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, concatenation, python-itertools

I have two lists like:

```
listone = [1, 2, 3]
listtwo = [4, 5, 6]
```

I would like to combine them to get:

```
l = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

How can I do this without using loops?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` and `zip`:

**Code:**

```
import itertools as it
list(it.chain(*zip(listone, listtwo)))
```

**Test Code:**

```
listone = [1, 2, 3]
listtwo = [4, 5, 6]
print(list(it.chain(*zip(listone, listtwo))))
```

**Results:**

```
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use *list slicing* feature of the list as:

```
>>> new_list = listone + listtwo  # create initial list of `len` equal
                                  # to `listone + listtwo`
>>> new_list[::2] = listone
>>> new_list[1::2] = listtwo
>>> new_list
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Another very simple way to achieve this is via using [**`zip()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with nested *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> listone = [1, 2, 3]
>>> listtwo = [4, 5, 6]

>>> [b for a in zip(listone, listtwo) for b in a]
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a variant using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
listone = [1, 2, 3]
listtwo = [4, 5, 6]

l = list(a for ab in zip(listone, listtwo) for a in ab)
print(l)  # [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use numpy (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays))

```
import numpy as np

listone = [1, 2, 3] 
listtwo = [4, 5, 6]

l=np.empty((len(listone)+len(listtwo)))
l[0::2]=listone
l[1::2]=listtwo

print l
>>> l = [ 1.  4.  2.  5.  3.  6.]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can plus two lists directly .

```
list_one=[1,2,3]  
list_two=[4,5,6]  
list_one=list_one+list_two  
print(list_one)

>>>list_one=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

you can also change the order of sum ,
then print out [4,5,6,1,2,3].

Comment: I think OP wants the list in this order `[1,4,2,5,3,6]`

Comment: Yes you are right , i forgot that