# Interleave numpy arrays with numeric comparison quickly

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interleave

I have 2 Python lists of integers.  The lists are possibly different sizes.  One is a list of indices of all the maxima in a dataset, and the other is a list of indices of all the minima. I want to make a list of consecutive maxes and mins in order, and skipping cases where, say, 2 mins come between 2 maxes.

Speed matters most, so I'm asking how the following can done most quickly (using Numpy, I assume, [a la this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5347492/682515)): What numpy code can make up `some_function()` below to do this calculation?

```
>>> min_idx = [1,5,7]
>>> max_idx = [2,4,6,8]
>>> some_function(min_idx, max_idx)
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

In the above example, we looked to see which `*_idx` list started with the lower value and chose it to be "first" (`min_idx`).  From there, we hop back and forth between `min_idx` and `max_idx` to pic "the next biggest number":

1. Start with 1 from `min_idx`
2. Look at `max_idx` to find the first unused number which is larger than 1: 2
3. Go back to `min_idx` to find the first unused number which is larger than 2: 5
4. Again for `max_idx`: we skip 4 because it's less than 5 and chose 6
5. continue process until we run out of values in either list.

As another example, for `min_idx = [1,3,5,7,21]` and `max_idx = [4,6,8,50]`, the expected result is `[1,4,5,6,7,8,21,50]`

My current non-Numpy solution looks like this where `idx` is the output:

```
# Ensure we use alternating mins and maxes
idx = []
max_bookmark = 0
if min_idx[0] < max_idx[0]:
    first_idx = min_idx
    second_idx = max_idx
else:
    first_idx = max_idx
    second_idx = min_idx
for i, v in enumerate(first_idx):
    if not idx:
        # We just started, so put our 1st value in idx
        idx.append(v)
    elif v > idx[-1]:
        idx.append(v)
    else:
        # Go on to next value in first_idx until we're bigger than the last (max) value
        continue

    # We just added a value from first_idx, so now look for one from second_idx
    for j, k in enumerate(second_idx[max_bookmark:]):
        if k > v:
            idx.append(k)
            max_bookmark += j + 1
            break
```

Unlike other answers about merging Numpy arrays, the difficulty here is comparing element values as one hops between the two lists along the way.

### Background: Min/Max List

The 2 input lists to my problem above are generated by `scipy.argrelextrema` which has to be used twice: once to get indices of maxima and again to get indices of minima.  I ultimately just want a single list of indices of alternating maxes and mins, so if there's some scipy or numpy function which can find maxes *and* mins of a dataset, and return a list of indices indicating alternating maxes and mins, that would solve what I'm looking for too.

Comment: It's not clear why `[1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 8]` is supposed to be the output for the example input. `8` repeats twice, among other apparent problems.

Comment: I corrected a typo in my example and explained the examples significance with a bulleted list following the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler logic without using Numpy (note: this assumes that `max(min_idx) < max(max_idx)`:

```
min_idx = [1,3,5,7,21]
max_idx = [4,6,8,50]
res = []

for i in min_idx:
    if not res or i > res[-1]:
        pair = min([m for m in max_idx if m > i])
        res.extend([i, pair])
```

```
print(res)
>>> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 21, 50]
```

Comment: This works well so long as gaps between values aren't too large.  I'm still curious if there's a numpy-based way which would be faster.  Each list will really be ~10 elements long spaced 10 or so apart like `[11, 25, 32, 46, 60, 71, 79, 85, 91]`

Comment: The 2nd line of the look requires a min_idx & max_idx value to be consecutive, and the input data is not like that.  For `min_idx = [1,3,5,7,21]` and `max_idx = [4,6,8,50]`, the expected result is `[1,4,5,6,7,8,21,50]`, but your code gives `[3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

Comment: @hamx0r ah, I understand now - would you mind editing your question to include this more robust example?

Comment: This approach works, @ukemi, though I'm still curious if there's a straightforward numpy solution since numpy tends to be faster with number crunching than raw python.