# How to insert tensor array into tensor matrix after every second position

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor array *a* and a tensor matrix *m*. Now I want to insert *a* into *m* after every second position started at index 0 ending with len(*m*)-2. Let's make an equivalent example using numpy and plain python:

```
# define m
m = np.array([[3,7,6],[4,3,1],[8,4,2],[2,8,7]])
print(m)
#[[3 7 6]
# [4 3 1]
# [8 4 2]
# [2 8 7]]

# define a
a = np.array([1,2,3])
#[1 2 3]

# insert a into m
result = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    result.append(a)
    result.append(m[i])
print(np.array(result))
#[[1 2 3]
# [3 7 6]
# [1 2 3]
# [4 3 1]
# [1 2 3]
# [8 4 2]
# [1 2 3]
# [2 8 7]]
```

I am looking for a solution in tensorflow. I am convinced that there is a solution that doesn't need a loop but I am not able to find one. I hope someone can help me out with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your target vector at the beginning of each line of your matrix, and then reshape it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

initial_array = tf.constant([
    [3, 7, 6],
    [4, 3, 1],
    [8, 4, 2],
    [2, 8, 7],
])

vector_to_add = [1, 2, 3]
concat = tf.concat([[vector_to_add] * initial_array.shape[0], initial_array], axis=1)  # Concatenate vector_to_add to each vector of initial_array
output = tf.reshape(concat, (2 * initial_array.shape[0], initial_array.shape[1]))  # Reshape
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
np.ravel(np.column_stack((m, np.tile(a, (4, 1))))).reshape(8, 3)
```

For idea, please refer to [Interweaving two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays). Apply any solution described there, and reshape.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a solution in tensorflow! I only provided a numpy example for clarity.