# Vector generation using numpy in Python

Tags: numpy

how to create a vector with numpy array with alternate 0 and 1 for desired number of rows
vectors of zeros or ones can be created with np.zeros(n) or np.ones(n).
Is there any way to create vector of alternate zeros and ones like [0,1,0,1,0,1]

Comment: You combine arrays made with `np.zeros` and `np.ones`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`np.tile`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```py
def zeros_and_ones(n):
    repeats = (n + 1) // 2
    return np.tile([0, 1], repeats)[:n]

zeros_and_ones(7)
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

And more generally, see here: [Interweaving two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5347065/4960855).

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of zeros and set every other element to one:

```
a = np.zeros(1000)
a[1::2] = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, there is no function similar to `np.zeros` or `np.ones` which allows you to directly do that.
A simple way to create such an array is to first create an array of the final size using `np.zeros(2n)` (assuming you want n zeros and n ones), and then replacing half of the 0 values by 1:

```py
import numpy as np
n = 100
a = np.zeros(2*n)
for i in range(n):
    a[2*i+1] = 1
```

Comment: While there exists no single function to do this, a for loop is not the right answer.