# Combine two 3D tensor (Pytorch) alternatively

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I want to combine two 3D tensors (Pytorch) alternatively

```
import torch
x = torch.ones(2, 2, 2, requires_grad=False, dtype=torch.float64)
y = torch.zeros(2, 2, 2, requires_grad=False, dtype=torch.float64)

#The results I want are
#Slicing[:,:,0]
#1010
#1010
#Slicing[:,:,1]
#1010
#1010
```

I found this one from the previous question ([Interweaving two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays)), but I think it only works for 1d array (tensor)

```
import torch
x = torch.ones(2, 2, 2, requires_grad=False, dtype=torch.float64)
y = torch.zeros(2, 2, 2, requires_grad=False, dtype=torch.float64)
result=torch.ravel(torch.column_stack((x, y)))
print('Check\n',result)
```

Comment: You are right, can I change to```torch.dstack((x,y)).reshape(size, -1, size)``` if x and y are```(size, size, size, requires_grad=False, dtype=torch.float64)```

Comment: try this 
"output = torch.cat([x, y], dim=-1)
order = [0, 2, 1, 3]
output = output[:, :, order].permute(0, 2, 1)
print(output[:, :, 0])"