# Get color from list of tuples python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a numpy array which I convert into a list of tuples like this

```
orig_img = cv2.imread("plane.jpg")


def cvimg_to_list(img: numpy.ndarray) -> list:
    img_lst = [] 
    img_row = img.shape[0] # Width
    img_column = img.shape[1] # Height

    for x in range(0, img_row): # (Width * Height)
        for y in range(0, img_column): 
            img_lst.append((img[x,y][0],  #B value
                            img[x,y][1],  #G value
                            img[x,y][2])) #R value

    return img_lst

orig_list = cvlib.cvimg_to_list(orig_img)
print(orig_list) #hundreds of thousands of values

>>> [(139, 80, 48), (135, 82, 39), ...]
```

Now I want to write a function *generator_from_image* which takes a image and returns a function which given an index for a pixel returns the color of that pixel.

The functions that are returned should look like the representation for images as one-dimensional lists. The return value for index 0 is the pixel in the upper left corner, the return value for the width of the image is the upper right corner, and so on.

Here's what I tried:

```
def generator_from_image(img):
    
    def get_color_from_index(x, y):
        color = (x, y) #Need help here...
        return color

    return get_color_from_index(img)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to have a double Python loop over each pixel in the image to get what you want. You can split the image into R,G,B channels using cv2.split(image) to 3 grayscale images. Then you can flatten each to 1D arrays using np.flatten(). Then you can interweave them using np.ravel(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays for interweaving.  Then you can use array.tolist to convert the previous result to a list. This should be much faster than what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

- If what you want is to return the original pixel at (x,y) with `generator_from_image` taking the list of pixels as input, you will need the original image shape of the image which was `(img_row, img_column, 3)` for instance:

you can do:

```
def generator_from_image(img):
    
    def get_color_from_index(x, y):
        color = img[x*img_column + y]
        return color

    return get_color_from_index
```

What is done here is jumping `x` times the number of comuns `img_column`  of the original image and adding `y` to reach the flattened index.

- Also, instead of looping through `img_row` and `img_column` and `append` the pixels, you can just do: `img.reshape((-1, 3)).tolist()` to get a list or `img.reshape((-1, 3))` to get a numpy array.